# How to group data on column and sum the record per hour on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection as below

```
"InteractionId": "1e4ab424-e3ab-4cc1-8642-c37bb6248a09",
"ArticleType": "Article",
"TransactionDate": ISODate("2019-06-27T16:44:16.307+05:30")
```

Note that the "ArticleType" can be of different type, Now I want to get the hourly count of ArticleType.

I have tried some of the queries but that did not worked.

```
USER_INTERACTIONS1.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      ArticleType: "$ArticleType",
      datePartDay: {
        $concat: [
          { $substr: [{ $dayOfMonth: "$TransactionDate" }, 0, 2] },
          "-",
          { $substr: [{ $month: "$TransactionDate" }, 0, 2] },
          "-",
          { $substr: [{ $year: "$TransactionDate" }, 0, 4] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: { TransactionDate: "$datePartDay", ArticleType: "$ArticleType" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
]);
```

Comment: @philoez98 i am updating my question.

Comment: @philoez98 this is additional information group by hourly

Comment: Please show us what you have tried until now